# Selenium: Open jstree Nodes using Node name as String

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm trying to automatize some test in order to open Jstree Nodes, using the Node name
I would like to make it clicking the arrow at the left of the node, instead of double-clicking the node itself.

Here is the code:

```
public void abrirSistema(String node) {
    Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + node + "')]")).size() > 0;
    if (isPresent) {
        System.out.println("System está abierto");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hay que abrir el sistema");
        WebElement system = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + node + "')]"));
        WebElement parent = system.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
        String parentId = parent.getAttribute("id");
        WebElement flecha = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"" + parentId + "\"]/i"));
        // WebElement arrow = parent.findElement(By.className("jstree-icon"));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", arrow);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(flecha));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(flecha)).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So basically I locate the Node by the name, cause elements on the tree changes dynamically, then pick the arrow, and click it.
The thing is that sometimes the code works, sometimes it doesn't, and I cannot figure it out why.

I make sure that page is full loaded before trying to run this, and when I run the Scenario, the step is always green although the Node is not opened

Also I would like to let you know that this code runs always after opening the root node, which is working properly. Just in case

Hope someone could help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you mind sharing the html code and some context with us? Did you try to replace the ```Thread.sleep()``` statements? And I assume that ```wait```is a ```WebDriverWait```instance.